# Loss function in tensorflow for an equation

Tags: python, tensorflow, loss-function

This is the loss function that I am trying to write in tensorflow. But the issue is that when I give different labels i.e. ground truths then the loss doesn't change. If I change the training image it does change. Also, if I give a perfect image and it's groundtruth, loss is quite greater than 0. From what I understand, Ix Iy and My My are image and label's x and y gradients(edges). 
Magnitude=square root of Mx^2+My^2.

The link of paper is:-

[Hairmatte net](https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.07168)

[image]

```
def sobelLoss(yPred,yTrue,input_img):
    yTrue=tf.image.rgb_to_grayscale(input_img)
    yPred=tf.image.rgb_to_grayscale(yPred)
    #converted label and image to grayscale
    I=tf.image.image_gradients(yTrue)
    M=tf.image.image_gradients(yPred)
    #calculate gradients of X and Y axis
    Ix=I[0]
    Mx=M[0]
    Iy=I[1]
    My=M[1]
    #flatten all matrices
    Ix=tf.reshape(Ix,[-1])
    Mx=tf.reshape(Mx,[-1])
    Iy=tf.reshape(Iy,[-1])
    My=tf.reshape(My,[-1])

    i=0
    total=1*32*32   # how much to loop
    sum=tf.constant([0],dtype='float32')
    #to add all of them together
    for i in range(total):
        r=tf.multiply(Ix[i],Mx[i])
        r1=tf.multiply(Iy[i],My[i])
        r2=tf.add(r,r1)
        r3=tf.square(r2)
        one=tf.constant([1],dtype='float32')
        r4=one-r3
        r5=tf.square(Mx[i])
        r6=tf.square(My[i])
        r7=tf.add(r5,r6)
        r8=tf.sqrt(r7)
        sum=tf.add(tf.multiply(r8,r4),sum)

    m1=tf.square(Mx)
    m2=tf.square(My)
    m3=tf.add(m1,m2)
    m4=tf.sqrt(m3)
    m5=tf.reduce_sum(m4)
    lc=tf.div(sum,m5)
    return lc

from skimage.transform import resize


x = resize(train_images[0], (32, 32), anti_aliasing=True)
x=np.expand_dims(x,axis=0)

print(x.shape)

y = resize(test_images[4], (32, 32), anti_aliasing=True)
y=np.expand_dims(y,axis=0)

print(y.shape)

import numpy as np
x=tf.convert_to_tensor(x,np.float32)
y=tf.convert_to_tensor(y,np.float32)

print(sobelLoss1(x,y,x))

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(sobelLoss(x,y,x)))
```

Kindly tell me what I am doing wrong in reproducing this loss function.
Any help in understanding this loss function and how to code it in tensorflow will be highly appreciated.

Comment: can you provide a link for a paper?

Comment: I have edited the question, kindly see it now.